# Performance debugging similar to Microsoft PerfTrack, but for Objective C?

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, debugging

Lately, I've been wondering about the existence of performance debugging tools for Objective-C i.e. iPad and iPhone applications.

I am familiar with PerfTrack by Microsoft which is integrated within Windows 7 and allows for detection of performance bottlenecks at deployment-site.

It measures performance in terms of a comparison between actual and maximum response time of a function to perform.

My question is, is there anything alike for tracking performance on deployment-size for native iPad || iPhone apps?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm blessed to say that I haven't uses Windows in nearly a decade but there is an application that gets installed with Xcode called Instruments. That can measure many different aspects of iOS and OS X apps.